# Otros dispositivos no pueden acceder a mi url la cual está sin sin publicar

Tags: php, web, url

Tengo una página PHP que aún no está publicada y por lo tanto está en localhost.

Desde mi ordenador se puede acceder, pero cuando hago un `StringRequest` a un archivo PHP no funciona, ya que es otro dispositivo y no encuentra la URL.

Mi pregunta es si existe alguna forma de que el emulador pueda acceder a esa URL sin haberla publicado, y si ya puestos, aunque creo que es imposible, existe alguna forma de que otros dispositivos puedan acceder s la URL sin haberla publicado.

¿Existiría sino alguna forma de publicarla gratuitamente para desarrollarla y probarla antes de ser lanzada?

He revisado la IP varias veces y es correcta, y un usuario de esta plataforma me dijo que el problema es que no todos los dispositivos podían acceder a esa URL.

Comment: Debes abrir el puerto 80 para aceptar peticiones externas, pero depende del sistema operativo y configuración del servidor web.

Comment: @Triby Muchas gracias. Lo probaré y ya te diré.

Comment: Una cosa que se me pasó decirte, eso solo funcionará si los dispositivos están conectados en la misma red del equipo. Si quieres acceder desde fuera de tu red, tal vez necesitarás un servicio como https://www.noip.com/

Comment: @Triby Gracias. Creo que en principio o no lo voy a tener que utilizar que en un futuro seguro. Gracias. :)